# Select two tables and ignore duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, database, duplicates

I have two tables, I need to count how many unique rows exist in those two tables

Here's an example.

```
Master Table
--------------------------- 
topicId | category | type   
--------------------------- 
1       |    2     |   1    
2       |    2     |   1    
3       |    2     |   1    
1       |    2     |   2   
---------------------------

User Table
---------------------------
topicId | category | type
---------------------------
1       |    2     |   1
5       |    2     |   1
7       |    2     |   2
---------------------------
```

The topicId is not unique but they are unique per type, there may be more categories but it's not relevant for this exemple

I would expect the result to be 6 rows

```
Result
---------------------------
topicId | category | type
---------------------------
1       |    2     |   1  <- present on both, only one shows
1       |    2     |   2  <- present on master, same id as above row but diferent type
2       |    2     |   1  <- present on master
3       |    2     |   1  <- present on master
5       |    2     |   1  <- present on user
7       |    2     |   2  <- present on user
----------------------------
```

Right now I query the two tables and run the ids through a function that removes duplicates but I think this is to complex, is there a way to count the rows in a single query?

Comment: Did you try UNION

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `union`:

```
select topicId, category, type from master_table
union 
select topicId, category, type from user_table
```

If you want to sort the resultset, then:

```
(select topicId, category, type from master_table)
union 
(select topicId, category, type from user_table)
order by topicId, category, type
```